# Sever networking stops after few hours but works after suspend/wakeup

Tags: linux, ubuntu, windows-server-2008, networking

I have an Ubuntu 12.10 Desktop PC acting as my headless home server. I can ping it and access the files and folders on the computer with no issues. But after a few hours of running, its networking stops working. I can no longer ping it or access any files on it.

Every morning I cannot access the server. But if I suspend it and then again wake it up, the networking starts working again !

I tried solving it for days with no luck. The PC had Windows Server 2008 on it before Ubuntu and it had the exact same issue.

What could be causing the problem ? For 10 days, I have tried almost everything there is in terms of OS/software configuration, registry tweaks, etc. Doesn't seem like a software issue.

I have an ASUS P8Z77-V motherboard. I feel that this board could be having some power saving features if there is no mouse or keyboard input for hours. Since this is a headless server, it might be the cause. But I read the manual for the motherboard and googled but still couldn't find any clue towards some sort of power saving feature.

Comment: usually such b=behavior indicates a network card/driver problem

Comment: I did think about that too, but the fact that it works after a sleep/wakeup cycle made me think otherwise. Since the sleep/wakeup cycle doesn't affect the drivers. Also, the exact same problem on Windows Server 2008 and Ubuntu indicates it most likely not the driver. And I had the proper drivers when it had Windows on it.
Could be a network card problem though. But its a new motherboard. Will try replacing the mobo though.

Comment: wake-up triggers some hardware re-initialization

Comment: At what point does the machine stop responding? When it enters sleep? Is there anything in the system logs prior to wake up that might hint at what's going on? Are there BIOS settings for power saving?

Comment: I tried to pinpoint the exact time that it stops responding but it is difficult since it sometimes works for 7-8 hours without issues. I checked the system logs but they were mostly about software information stuff not any major errors and nothing especially related to the networking or ethernet controller. I checked the BIOS too. Found power saving for the CPU but not for the ethernet controller.